# Bochs enhanced debugger does not show 16-bit registers in 16-bit mode

Tags: bochs, mbr

I'm using the Bochs enhanced debugger on Windows 10 x64 to debug an MBR in 16-bit mode.

It all works perfectly fine, except that the debugger shows me 32-bit registers instead of 16-bit ones. I can still see all the info I need, but it gets a bit tedious.

I've seen plenty of Bochs screenshots where the registers shown in Real mode 16 are ax, bx, cx - etc. I've looked around the Bochs documentation, forums, everything, but I can't find a way to switch this.

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious here, but can anyone tell me how to change it to display the 16-bit registers?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a menu item under "Options" for "Show 32bit Registers" in the debugger console. I presume if you untick this it will show 16 bit registers.

I'm trying to do the same thing but my option for "Show 32bit Registers" is ghosted out. I'm wondering if you have the same?

Bochs "Show 32bit Registers" location -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn2Ov.png)

Comment: Greyed out here as well... my suspicion is that this switches between 32 and 64 bit registers, or shows 32 bit registers alongside 64 bit ones. There does not appear to be a way to show 16 bit registers in Bochs.